# Recovering output value in QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I use QGIS 3.0.3

In the graphical modeler, I use the algorithm "Basic statistics for fields".

Is there a way to recover the export values in the produced html file and using them in the modeler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]In 2.18 you can, for example, run the basic numeric stats and then use any value produced as a value for a fixed distance buffer (drop down menu in the buffer window). So, basically it is possible, but will depend on your data, the statistics you run and the intended use. Could you elaborate?